# Changing the Shape of Div using CSS or JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to change the div shape using css or jquery like below?

[image]

I have some content inside the div. Eg. Lorem ipsum... But I want the shape like this using css. Any possible way?

```css
#shape {
-moz-transform: skew(26deg, 0deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(26deg, 0deg);
-o-transform: skew(26deg, 0deg);
-ms-transform: skew(26deg, 0deg);
transform: skew(26deg, 0deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="shape">Lorem ipsum...</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your code so far.

Comment: try to use transform:rotate() property or transform:skew() property of CSS

Comment: Please check [this](https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/transform/) link to try css transforms.

Comment: @Lal, I tried the same already. Unable to get the shape like above. I want left side towards right side is increasing height like triangle. Exactly same like the above pic.

Comment: I have the reference here. http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/349x9/2111/. But How to change it towards my requirement?

Comment: This will work https://jsfiddle.net/oxwja1L7/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, The link which you provided, if we add some content, within the div, it shows like -90deg cclock wise.

Comment: @Shakthi like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lzgqmxrb/

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get the output. Thanks to all..

```
#shape {     
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(320deg); 
}
```

```
<div id="shape">Lorem ipsum...</div>
```